# Function Keys setting resets

Tags: macos, keyboard, settings

I prefer the default behavior of the Function keys on my Mac to act like old school standard function keys (F1, F2, etc.).

So I switch on the according setting in macOS 13: *Keyboard* / *Keyboard Shortcuts...* / *Function Keys* / *Use F1, F2, etc. keys as standard function keys*.

Since macOS 13.3 or so this setting keeps switching off mysteriously after a while.

So it works for a while after I switch it on, but then, after some time, when I press F12 for example, the volume goes up instead of whatever the F12 shortcut would do in the app I'm using. I check the settings, and the switch is turned off again.

I haven't noticed a particular pattern so far. I usually only reboot for OS upgrades, so I don't think it's caused by reboots.

I guess it's a macOS bug, but then there should be more than just me experiencing this. Anyone else having this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I discovered a setting in Porting Kit which I use to play some old Windows games which says "*Switch F1-F12 keys function to Fn functions while in game*".

That gave me the idea that maybe Porting Kit is reverting my macOS setting and I was actually able to confirm this: Porting Kit is messing with my macOS setting for the Function keys.